# Raspberry Pi cannot acces internet through Laptop (connected via Ethernet)

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ethernet, internet

I'm currently using a raspberry pi 3. Even though it comes with a built in wifi card, it does not seem to find any wlan interface. I think this is due to the operating system being an older version. To fix this problem, I tried to connect the pi to the internet through my laptop using an ethernet cable and update it. Installing a new operating on the SD-Card is out of question, since the pi is not mine and might have important data/configuration. The problem I'm facing right now is that the pi cannot connect to the internet. I tried to configure the connection method to 'shared to other computers', it did not work. I also followed this tutorial https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6997&p=87671
At first it worked, the pi would connect to it, but I recently upgraded the Kernel on my Laptop and since then it is not working anymore.

I'm starting to get really desperate, I couldn't find anything to solve this problem.
Is it possible that the firewall is blocking the connection? If so how can I configure it?

NOTE: My laptop is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: have you considered getting a second SD card?

Comment: no, I'm also using other pi's (older versions with wifi dongle) they also have the same issue. I'm looking for a quick fix to be honest

Comment: It seems as though you think the problem is with the firewall on your Laptop - which is not really an RPi problem IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got WIFI working now! The issue was that the wifi needed to be configured with the correct locale to access WIFI. `sudo iwlist channel` returned channels from `1 to 11`, however to access the WIFI from my current location it needed to have at least 12 or 13 channels.

For anyone who has the same problem, this might help you:

This is how my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

To establish a connection to your WIFI change this file
`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:
(It's important that country code is given here)

```
country=NL
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
   ssid="YOUR-WIFI"
   #if you do not have any password then use this
   key_mgmt=NONE 
   #else put your password like this
   psk="your-password"
}
```

To configure the channels execute these:

```
dmesg -T | grep -iE 'domain|region'
cat /etc/default/crda
```

if it the locale is empty, then set it to NL:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda

iw reg get
sudo iw reg set NL #your country code
iw reg get
iwlist wlan0 channel
```

The output should show more than 11 channels.
Now it shoud be rebooted!

The only thing I found strange is, that the pi cannot detect any wireless interfaces on the GUI, however it still connects to the WIFI